# C# Unity Raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a reversed mesh sphere, with the normals pointing inside, and 6 planes making a cubemap outside this sphere, algo with the normals pointing inside.

I want to know the position of a raycast hit from camera in (0,0,0), also the center of those two figures, to the sphere.

I tryed to use convex mesh collider but the sphere has to much vertex and Unity doesn´t support it. My idea was to check the collision to the cube, and then make a collision to the sphere (with a normal sphere collider) with the direction reversed from the camera.

*The second Raycast should come to the point of the first collision and collide with the sphere, but it reports that "print("I'm looking at nothing!");"*

```
    public void launchBttn()
{
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("coordText").GetComponent<Text>().text = transform.forward.ToString();

    Ray rayBox = GetComponent<Camera>().ViewportPointToRay(transform.forward);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(rayBox, out hit))
        print("I'm looking at " + hit.transform.name);
    else
        print("I'm looking at nothing!");

    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("collText").GetComponent<Text>().text = hit.transform.position.ToString();

    Vector3 fwd = -transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    RaycastHit hitSphere;
    if (Physics.Raycast(hit.transform.position, fwd, out hitSphere))
    {
        print("I'm looking at " + hitSphere.transform.name);

    }
    else
    {
        print("I'm looking at nothing!");
    }

    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("sphereCollText").GetComponent<Text>().text = hitSphere.transform.position.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? It's not stated very well in the question

Comment: Oh, sorry my fault, the second raycast apoints that "I´m looking at nothing!"
But it has no sense to me...

It should be colliding to the sphere collider.

Comment: Why not https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html with a reasonable maxDistance, instead of "inverse raycasting"? Also, did you try to Debug.DrawRay to see where your casts are going?

Comment: Never tryed DrawRay, i´m gonna try now. Maybe RaycastAll could solve it if i tag the colliders, thanks. I´ll update this with more info.

Comment: If it's always a sphere and it's always centered on 0,0,0 why bother raycasting anyway? You know which direction your ray is being cast, just set the length of the vector to the radius of the sphere and you have your point of intersection... Simple trig